# How do I secure my internet line from being spied on by my landlord?

Tags: networking, router, internet

I hope this question fits in the site scope and is not too broad.

I'm moving to a new apartment soon. In this new apartment I have a nice internet line with 100mb/s download (I had 10mb/s in my former apartment so you can guess I'm very excited for that).

The landlord is an IT Professional. He has two Linux servers in the basement which are connected to this 100mb/s line. there's also a router in there, I don't exactly know the order of the router and server, but what I'm sure is that my apartment is also connected to his servers and router. So basically I wouldn't need a router in my apartment but could just put a switch in the network and would receive internet from his router.

The benefit I have from this is that I don't have to pay anything for my internet connection which is pretty nice. But I'm concerned about one thing: the Security of my personal data.

My question would be, what can I do to get my part of the network as save as possible so that my landlord can't really see what I'm doing, without loosing too much Internet speed.

I could think of the following options (I'm not a network pro at all, maybe there's an error in my logic):

- Setting up my own router and creating my own subnet which he can't access in any way (but with this way there are two NATs which could compromise the Internet speed)
- Ask my landlord to put my apartment in a isolated VLAN
- Ask my landlord to put my apartment in a seperate Internet line and pay for the internet.
- Don't do anything and just configure an acces point for WLAN (no security for me)

Are there any other things I can do to make sure my landlord can't see my personal data and can't get my passwords for online accounts etc.? I guess a firewall just for my apartment wouldn't get me any benefits.

Just to clarify, I don't think my landlord would even want to have or see my personal data, but I always want to be as secure as possible.

What would you do in my situation?

Comment: No matter what you do as long as you go in INet over his router you can't be save, it is possible to log all your activities.

Comment: Do option 3, it is the only way to be sure.

Comment: You follow the same general rules as you would if connecting to a public Wi-Fi hotspot. Namely: [HTTPS where possible](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) for end-to-end security, especially for any sensitive data like banking details. VPN for non-HTTPS sites, if you want to go the extra mile - but you'd have to trust the VPN provider, who has just as much visibility of your traffic as your landlord would have. Really, end-to-end authenticated encryption (HTTPS) is the *only* way to prevent snooping between you and the intended recipient.

Comment: Just setup your router between your LAN and apartment's network. There way too many places who can spy on you while you are in internet and landlord might be just one them in a chain, so either use VPN to trusted(?) host outside or better get a beer and make friendship with landlord

Comment: I'm pretty certain your landlord has better things to do than monitor you internet traffic

Comment: Do you have your own landline for phone? If so, why can't you just get your own DSL? or if you have a separate cable line, your own cable service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you think the the threat is.

If you're worried about someone getting *in* and rummaging through a properly set up firewall would work fine.

If you're worried about someone looking at your traffic - tough. Short of encrypting everything from where you are to where you're connecting through - a lot of traffic passes through as plain text - though anything that's sensitive ought to be done over TLS . I'd get a VPS or other server and do sensitive stuff through a VPN *I* control if I was in an untrusted network all the time.

If you're worried about *passwords* - use TFA where possible (so even if your passwords are sniffed in your network, you still have the third factor to add a bit more of security).

That said, he's a *geek* , be curious and ask him how its set up and he'll be too happy to tell you. Ask him how to secure it (from other tenants?) and all you need to do is polish up.

There's no real benefit for a landlord to snoop your traffic (and there's usually much too much - which is why most non governmental and even governmental types block first, and snoop selectively) and an angry tenant whose privacy has been violated will be a pain.

Answer (score -2):

> setting up my own router and creating an own subnet which he can't
>   access in any way (but with this way there are two NATs which could
>   compromise the Internet speed)

This would stop him being able to sniff around your LAN. However, you will always have the problem that your Internet bound traffic is going through his equipment and subject to sniffing and MITM attacks (even if using https). The only sure way to avoid this is to use a VPN. You would want it permanently connected (perhaps by setting up a router or other gateway device to maintain the connection). There are publicly available VPN services or you could set up your own by connecting into a hosted server somewhere (e.g. Amazon or Digital Ocean).

Comment: *> subject to sniffing and MITM attacks (even if using https)* Uh, no. Unless you're dumb enough to accept invalid certificates, HTTPS *specifically* protects against both active and passive MitM attacks.

Comment: @Bob, So I'm wrong, expect in the case of an exception? Therefore, I am right.

Comment: What on earth kind of logic is that? Sure, if you go out of your way to toss security out the window, it's insecure. VPNs are likewise insecure if you accept invalid certificates. But you do not make this distinction in any way in your answer. Your claim, that HTTPS allows MitM attacks in the general case, is wrong without that qualification.

Comment: I was being facetious. My point is, to blanket say "you cannot be hacked/hijacked/whatever if using https" is to instil a false sense of security. Yes, you may need to take some manual steps to get caught out, but there are ways. It may not even need that - his landlord could set up a proxy that redirects all his https traffic to port 80 or something. Also, there's this: https://news.netcraft.com/archives/2016/03/17/95-of-https-servers-vulnerable-to-trivial-mitm-attacks.html.

Comment: Ah, protocol downgrade 'attacks'. Where prevention is as simple as checking the address bar of your browser before proceeding with entering any sensitive details. If this were a concern, it would've been nice if you included the risks, warnings and solution in your answer. (And if I were to be pedantic... yes, if you are actually using HTTPS, sslstrip-esque attacks won't work. They only work on the *pre-*HTTPS step if someone accidentally/insecurely requests the HTTP version first.) The rest of your answer is decent enough advice - I just disagree with the HTTPS bit (not my downvotes...)